# Redirect to login.aspx page to log in if I directly open Home.aspx page

Tags: asp.net, authentication, redirect

I have a site with a `Login.aspx` page and a `Home.aspx` page. If I want to open my home page without logging in, it should redirect to `Login.aspx` page to log in. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this on your config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".FormsAuth" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All"/>
 </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Comment: it's working.. if i try to open home page it redirects to log in page to login.. great work..! thanx. But problem is that it does not allow to log in if i write correct username and password. I want that the users those are already have their accounts can log in in the website.. It should take username and password from database table and do authentication. PLS RPL if u can help me. thnx

Comment: pls if you can upload that code or can tell me the process path that can solve this problem. thnx in advance